# iPhone SDK > 4.1, UISearchBar does not respond to keyboard input if subview of an UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, iphone-sdk-4.1

Testing in the simulator for iPhone SDK > 4.1, UISearchBar does not respond to keyboard input if it is a subview of an UIAlertView.

Tests on the iPad simulator 3.2 and on a 3.1 iPod Touch device both succeed, while on the 4.1 and 4.2 simulators, I can only use the keyboard to delete existing text (that I set from code), not to input text: the typing animation appears, yet no text is inputted in the UISearchBar.

There is no such behavior when using an UITextField, so it further strikes me as a very curious bug.

Can anyone else test this on a real > 4.1 device and confirm/infirm this and perhaps come up with a solution/workaround?

Comment: Why are you having a search bar in an alert view? Are you sure this follows the iOS Human Interface Guidelines?

Comment: @Time Machine It's not an app meant for the AppStore, it's for personal use on a jailbroken device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's a simulator problem, the actual devices run the code in this scenario with no issues whatsoever.